# Is this an example of blackmail or is it called something else?

Tags: word-choice

If someone says "You will only get X, once you're done being my slave" is this blackmail or it is called something else? From my understanding blackmail involves threats and I don't see a clear threat in that statement.

Comment: I suppose it depends on what X is, and whether the person should normally be able to get X without having to be a slave.

Answer (score 1):

The answer depends crucially on what X is.

It's **extortion** that requires a threat.  Extortion is a crime, a form of theft, in which someone employs coercion to obtain another's property or services.  Coercion usually involves a threat of force.  Suppose X="free of a beating," then you have **extortion**:

> You will only get free of a beating, once you're done being my slave.

Coercion in the US is defined differently in different jurisdictions.  E.g., in New Jersey (among other states), a threat to provide damaging testimony in a trial or withhold favorable testimony constitutes coercion.  So if X="alibi testimony," that's extortion (at least in New Jersey):

> You will only get my testimony giving you an alibi, once you're done
>   being my slave.

**Blackmail** is the threat to reveal damaging information about someone unless he hands over his property or performs services.  Suppose X="the negatives", then you have **blackmail**:

> You will only get the negatives, once you're done being my slave.

But suppose X="the hundred dollars," then perhaps all you've got is a kinky proposition:

> You will only get the hundred dollars, once you're done being my
>   slave.

As long the "slave" is free to walk away at any time, albeit unrewarded, there's no crime.

Comment: Depending on the number of hours of "slavery" required, or the conditions of the slavery, there might be a violation of minimum wage or other labor laws.

Comment: @phoog In the US, minimum wage and labor laws usually don't apply to personal service agreements.  And actions that would be a crime without consent can be legal with it, so if the slavery involves the slave agreeing to be whipped, that's just wholesome sadomasochism as long as the slave can withdraw consent.  Some actions cannot be made legal in the US by consent.  The slave in this example could not consent to his execution.

Comment: Thanks for that. So blackmail and extortion both involve threats but the distinction between the two is that the threats usually associated with blackmail don't involve coercion ? Also can blackmail be a form of extortion ?

Comment: If X was "my affection" then would that just be classed as a proposition or is there a better word to describe the statement "You will only get my affection once you're done being my slave"

Comment: @deadrat domestic employees are covered by minimum wage law, and a domestic employee's consent to be paid less does not absolve the employer from complying with the law.

Comment: @phoog Who's going to complain?  And domestic employees haven't been slaves in the US in 9/18/65.  1865.

Comment: @deadrat I am imagining "you will only get the $100 when you finish being my slave" -"okay, what do you want me to do?" -"act as my butler for a week."  Regardless of whether anyone complains, a crime will have been committed.

Comment: @phoog Then what you're imagining isn't a slave, now is it?

Comment: @deadrat as far as I understand it, a slave is someone who has to do whatever you tell them to do.

Comment: @phoog I'm turning into that internet guy who has to have the last word in any combox, so I'm going to stop that.